# Creating subdomains - permissions

Tags: linux, php, file-permissions, netbeans

At my work, I sometimes write small applications for visual information on a web based platform (LAOP-jQuery). Some of my colleagues have started doing this as well in order to have better access to information. They, however, are not as familiar with command-line Linux as myself (and I'm only a novice really) and so everytime someone wan't to create a new app, they contact me and I make a dummy subdomain (a new folder on the server) with a requested name and let them take over. What I do is just copy a folder that contains a standard html-php template with a few functions and database connections that we use.

I am currently trying to limiting my work by creating a small app that does this work for me. It's quite simple and stupid really. They go to a link I provided, enter a password and a domain name of their choice and then click "create".
Behind the scenes a php-system() function is called that copies a directory called "dummy" to /var/www/oursite/apps/.

Example:
Jane goes to the "create new domain" page. She enters the correct password and chooses a name for her domain "foobar".

A system function is called:

> system('cp -r ../../dummy
> ../../apps/'.filter_input(INPUT_POST,'domain_name'));
>
> // which translates to: system('cp -r ../../dummy
> ../../apps/foobar');

and thus, I now have a directory /apps/foobar

Here comes the problem. The permissions on "foobar" are the following:

> drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data www-data 4096 Mar  1 11:48 foobar

That is, owned by the user and group www-data:www-data

When I connect to this folder (through NetBeans) using a developer user "dev" **which is a part of the www-data group** I can download the files, but I cannot edit them as the group www-data does not have write permissions to the newly created "foobar" directory.

How can I make this work the way I want?

Thanks in advance
Benedikt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from a friend of mine.
He basically told me about the unmask function in php, and although it is probably not the most secure method nor the "best-practice" this is what I did:

> ```
> $old = umask(0); // clear permissions for new files/dirs
>
> system('cp -r ../../dummy ../../apps/'.filter_input(INPUT_POST,'domain_name')); // copy the dummy
>
> chmod('../../apps/'.filter_input(INPUT_POST,'domain_name'),0775); // grant the group www-data permissions to edit the file/dir
>
> umask($old); // restore original mask
> ```

If anyone has a better way, I'd still like to hear it.

Thanks everyone

Benedikt

Answer (score 0):

The clever trick you can do is to execute this: `sudo adduser yourusername www-data`.

What it does: this commands add you to the group of www-data, which opens the access for you to get your hands dirty on the file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!. I did try that earlier, as stated in my question "... using a developer user "dev" which is a part of the www-data group ...". After creating the directory through the web-application, however, only the owner of the group www-data (the owner is also called www-data) can write, other's in the group could only read and execute.